# how check doinbackground(Void.. ar) method is completed in android

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am creating a program that fetch the value from online . I have use `AsynTask` class for background process. i am fetching the some values from web and set value in class variables.My problem is that values are setting in variables in very late. and my execution processed further and find variables values null. How can i check that `doInBackground()` method is processed completely and values are sets in variable. so that i can use these variables values.

Comment: u had not read asyntask class pls read it.

Comment: You can put LOG at the end of `doInBackground()` method.. to check that method has completed its execution.. You should set values of your variable in `onPostExecute()`....
For More Details read... [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Comment: set class variables in onPostExecute() method which is executed after doInBackground() method.

Comment: thanks KratosBala for giving idea..

Answer (score 0):

One of the best method is to use a kind of `observer` **design pattern**.

So first create an Interface with contain a method (depend on your return value, etc) :

```
public interface OnTaskCompleted{
    void onTaskCompleted(String xml);
}
```

Then you need to `implement` this interface to your **activity** wich *instantiate* your `asynctack`, see:

```
public class MainActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity implements OnTaskCompleted
```

Then to finish, you gonna pass the instance of MainActivity (wich by *polymorphisme* is also `OnTaskCompleted`) to your asyntask. *Here my asyntask class handler is named XMLParser*

```
public class XMLParser {

       private OnTaskCompleted listener;

    public XMLParser(OnTaskCompleted mainActivity, String url){
        getXMLFromURL(mainActivity,url);
    }

[......] 

//here when the work is done you call the OnTaskComplete Method
               @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
                        //CALL HERE
            listener.onTaskCompleted(result);
        }
}
```

I hope it'll help you. Works like a charm for me.